# What is a Lorentz boost and how to calculate it?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

I know very little about special relativity. I never learnt it properly, but every time I read someone saying

> If you boost in the $x$-direction, you get such and such

my mind goes blank! I tried understanding it but always get stuck with articles that assume that the reader knows everything.

So, what is a Lorentz boost, and how to calculate it? And why does the direction matter?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

[Lorentz boost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation#Boost_in_the_x-direction) is simply a Lorentz transformation which doesn't involve rotation. For example, Lorentz boost in the *x* direction looks like this:

\begin{equation}
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
\gamma & -\beta \gamma & 0 & 0 \newline
-\beta \gamma & \gamma & 0 & 0 \newline
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \newline
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right]
\end{equation}

where coordinates are written as *(t, x, y, z)* and

\begin{equation}
\beta = \frac{v}{c}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}}
\end{equation}

This is a linear transformation which given coordinates of an event in one reference frame allows one to determine the coordinates in a frame of reference moving with respect to the first reference frame at velocity *v* in the *x* direction.

The ones on the diagonal mean that the transformation does not change the *y* and *z* coordinates (i.e. it only affects time *t* and distance along the *x* direction). For comparison, Lorentz boost in the *y* direction looks like this:

\begin{equation}
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
\gamma & 0 & -\beta \gamma & 0 \newline
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \newline
-\beta \gamma & 0 & \gamma & 0 \newline
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right]
\end{equation}

which means that the transformation does not affect the *x* and *z* directions (i.e. it only affects time and the *y* direction).

In order to calculate Lorentz boost for any direction one starts by determining the following values:

\begin{equation}
\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{v_x^2+v_y^2+v_z^2}{c^2}}}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\beta_x = \frac{v_x}{c},
\beta_y = \frac{v_y}{c},
\beta_z = \frac{v_z}{c}
\end{equation}

Then the matrix form of the Lorentz boost for velocity *v=(v<sub>x</sub>, v<sub>y</sub>, v<sub>z</sub>)* is this:

\begin{equation}
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
L_{tt} & L_{tx} & L_{ty} & L_{tz} \newline
L_{xt} & L_{xx} & L_{xy} & L_{xz} \newline
L_{yt} & L_{yx} & L_{yy} & L_{yz} \newline
L_{zt} & L_{zx} & L_{zy} & L_{zz} \newline
\end{array}
\right]
\end{equation}

where

\begin{equation}
L_{tt} = \gamma
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
L_{ta} = L_{at} = -\beta_a \gamma
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
L_{ab} = L_{ba} = (\gamma - 1) \frac{\beta_a \beta_b}{\beta_x^2 + \beta_y^2 + \beta_z^2} + \delta_{ab} = (\gamma - 1) \frac{v_a v_b}{v^2} + \delta_{ab}
\end{equation}

where *a* and *b* are *x*, *y* or *z* and δ<sub>ab</sub> is the [Kronecker delta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta).

Comment: Could you please refer a reference where the elements of the lorentz transformation matrix for boost in general direction is calculated in an easy way.  I want to see how the elements of the matrix that you have shown are actually calculated.  Also I want to know what will be the transformation incase of a spatial rotation plus a lorentz boost

Comment: When is it usually applied? Or in other words: Why should I boost? I got it that it changes the frame to another frame but when I have to do extra work I will skip that. So why shall I boost?

Answer (score 7):

Did you check out the wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation?

Basically it is just a change of co-ordinates when you change your frame of reference from one that is at rest, to another frame which is moving w.r.t to it at a constant velocity $v$.If the changes inertial frame is moving along the x-axis of the old frame, with the y and z axis parallel to each other, it is called a lorentz boost in the x-direction. The change of co-ordinates can be found out using the lorentz transformation matrix give by Adam, or the co-ordinate transformation formula. These can be derived using the fact that the interval between two points $(ct)^2-x^2-y^2-z^2$ is lorentz invariant. Refer to chapter1 of [classical theory of fields](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0750627689) by Landau and Lifschitz.

Answer (score 2):

In a pithy sense, a Lorentz boost can be thought of as an action that imparts linear momentum to a system. Correspondingly, a Lorentz rotation imparts angular momentum. Both actions have a direction as well as a magnitude, and so they are vector quantities. They can be combined, and they can interact. Matrix (linear) algebra is often used for their calculations.