# Does an observer measure magnetic field when moving inside a static E field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, relativity

Imagine a static electric field shaped as a sinusoid created by an array of electrodes on an infinite line. Does an observer flying parallel inside this e-field measure an h-field ?

Comment: Some sort of diagram might help. In general yes, if you have a static E-field in one frame of reference then in a different moving frame of reference there will be both an E-field and B- (or H-) field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of special relativity is required to understand this. Electric and magnetic fields form a 4-vector with their potentials:

$$ A^{\mu} = (\phi, \vec{A}) $$

Where $ \phi $ is the scalar electric potential and $ \vec{A} $ is the magnetic potential. In the case you described, this would be:

$$ A^{\mu} = (\phi, 0) $$

Where $ \phi $ is constant in time and $ \vec{A} = 0 $. The observer, assuming they are moving in an inertial frame at velocity $ v $ in the x-direction, has undergone a [Lorentz boost](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/30166/what-is-a-lorentz-boost-and-how-to-calculate-it). In the observers frame, they measure $ A'^{\mu} $:

$$ A'^{\mu} = \Lambda^{\mu}_{\nu} A^{\nu} $$

Using [Einstein notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation#Statement_of_convention). Just think of this as a linear transformation acting on the 4-vector $ A^{\nu} $ (the original 4-potential). Therefore the elements of the new 4-vector are, using $ \Lambda $ from the link provided, produced upon using the matrix:

$$ \lambda^{\mu}_{\nu} = \begin{bmatrix}
    \gamma       & -\beta\gamma & 0 & 0 \\
    -\beta\gamma       & \gamma & 1 & 0 \\
    0       & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Which results in a new potential:

$$ A'^{\mu} = (\gamma \phi, -\beta \gamma \phi, 0, 0) $$

As you can see the 4-potential to the observer moving at constant velocity $ v $ has picked up a magnetic potential component in the direction of motion. The magnetic potential looks to him to be:

$$ \vec{A} = (-\beta\gamma\phi, 0, 0) $$

Which has a non-zero curl, and therefore produces a magnetic field. Notice that both terms have a factor of $ \gamma $, but only the second term has the factor of $ \beta $. For non-relativistic speeds $ \gamma \approx 1 $ and $ \beta = v/c \approx 0 $, which reduces the potentials back to their places.